# Power BI Report Server - Hide Folders & Display Toolbar

Tags: powerbi, toolbar, power-bi-report-server

I'm trying to come up with a URL parameter that gives me the results on the left side of the picture. Please note that I edited the HTML in my browser to get the desired results.

[image]

I have a Power BI report server. I usually add to the end of hyperlinks `?cs:Command=render&rc:Toolbar=false`. This bit of URL results in the image like this.
[image]

The issue here is that in the Power BI toolbar is removed, taking away viewing and print options from my users. I cannot ask my users to edit their HTML to get the desired results.

I went down a rabbit hole with url parameters, but maybe this isn't the solution. I've found some Microsoft documentation, but most of the URL parameters appear to not apply to Power BI reports, but other types of reports that can be placed on the report server. Every thing I have tried either results in the full tool bar being displayed, or none of it (3rd image). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#special-characters-in-table-and-column-names

I have a single dashboard that pulls the Report Server API and the users who have access to which reports. It then displays the reports a user has access to and all of the corresponding hyperlinks. My goal is to have the first option (green circle) displayed when they click on any hyperlink. I need any kind of url parameter that will hide the folder structure of the sever (red circle) without hiding the PBI toolbar (green circle).

I'm also open to other solutions if any are available.